Websocket Connection Nuxt AWS Lambda
This question may be a bit vague, but I am sure this is for a problem that others have or want to solve so I thought it worth asking for guidance here.
I am integrating stripe payment into my application. Part of this will involve waiting for stripe to process this payment. When stripe has finished it will send an HTTP request to my WebHook URL. I have two options of how to deal with this update: WebSocket or long polling. Long polling seems easier to implement, but WebSocket seems to be the cleaner option, but I am unsure how best to implement it in this situation. My front end is a Nuxt app hosted in Heroku, and my Webhook is an AWS Lambda behind API Gateway. The way I see it is that the Lambda, when invoked by the Webhook request, can send a push notification to the Nuxt client side, which is listening for notifications.
My questions:

Does this sound broadly correct, or an oversimplification? What am I missing if so?
How can the Nuxt front end verify websocket notifications without exposing anything private to the browser?
How can this work so that only the individual person paying receives the notification, not everyone making a payment at that time? I see Websockets are usually used for messaging.


You can also use SSE as explained here. Otherwise, it looks good yes! You'll figure out the minor details along the way. Nothing private need to sent to AWS so far, I recommend using some sort of UUID (or maybe just user's email?) so that you know which webhook response to match on AWS. For the only-person notification, use auth or filter by users (if user.email{ display()}). You can also use your Nuxt app (if SSR) to handle the backend part, here is a paid example
